# i cannot display my friends list in my personal html code and php code

Tags: php, html, facebook-friends

```
CREATE TABLE `friends` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_one` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  `user_two` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  `friendship_official` enum('0','1') NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE `registration` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `u_firstname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `u_lastname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `u_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,)
```

This is my Php code and i still dont have any html code. can anyone just echo these names in html and just correct this code

```
                         $friendsArray = "";
                         $countFriends = "";
                        $friendsArray12 = "";
                        $addAsFriend = "";
                        $selectFriendsQuery = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user_one=`$username` and friendship_official=`1`");
                        $friendRow = mysqli_fetch_array($selectFriendsQuery);
                        $friendArray = $friendRow[`user_two`];
                        if ($friendArray != "") {
                            $countFriends = count($friendArray);
                            $friendArray12 = array($countFriends);
                            $i = 0;
                        }
                            if ($countFriends != 0) {
                                foreach($friendArray12 as $key=>$value) {
                                 $i++;
                                 $getFriendQuery = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM registration WHERE u_name=`$value` LIMIT 1");
                                 $getFriendRow = mysqli_fetch_array($getFriendQuery);
                                 $friendUsername = $getFriendRow[`u_name`];

                                 $friendFirstname = $getFriendRow[`u_firstname`];
                                 $friendLastname = $getFriendRow[`u_lastname`];
                            } }
```

any tips are appricipated

Comment: this question is missing any code.

Comment: i edited this code

Comment: please help me to get this code runing

Comment: no php or html, really dont know how to help you.

Comment: is it okay now?

Comment: can anyone help me

Comment: i have uploaded php code  can anyone correct this php code and only echo in html

Comment: It is not understandable what you need. For example, `$friendArray` - it define as `VAR_CHAR` why do you use it as array? `$friendArray12` is array of 1 int but you search his value as name...

Comment: i m not geting it right sir ..will u help me

Comment: @ProAnimepro Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

this is your table of your friends

```
<?php
//  $username must be unique
     $friendsArray = array();
     $html='';
    $selectFriendsQuery = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user_one=`$username` and friendship_official=`1`");
     $countFriends = mysqli_num_rows($selectFriendsQuery);
   if ($countFriends>0) {
$html.="<table>
 <tr>
   <th>Username</th>
   <th>Full Name</th>
 </tr>";     
     while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($selectFriendsQuery)) {
        $user=$row['user_one']; 
          $getFriendQuery = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM registration WHERE u_name=`$user` LIMIT 1");
          $getFriendRow = mysqli_fetch_array($getFriendQuery);
        $html.="<tr>";     
  $html.= "<td>".$getFriendRow['u_name']."</td>";
  $html. = "<td>".$getFriendRow['u_firstname'].' '.$getFriendRow['u_lastname']."</td>";
    $html.="</tr>";     
}
$html.="</table>";     
    } 

    echo $html;
```